# getting powershell to class ie and during a ui test take a screenshot of the ie window

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, coded-ui-tests, ui-testing

So i'm running a ui test with power shell.

When i get an error i want to take a screen shot of just the ie window this can be done with alt print scrn

%{prtsc}

but it only takes a jpg of the active window.

I tryied this
 $h = (Get-Process iexplore).MainWindowHandle
 SetForegroundWindow((Get-Process -name iexplore).MainWindowHandle)
 sleep -sec 2
 $h = (Get-Process -id $pid).MainWindowHandle

Also any help with a way to identify ie error would be great thanks.

```
function screenshot
{
    param(    
    [Switch]$OfWindow        
    )
    begin {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
        $jpegCodec = [Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo]::GetImageEncoders() | 
            Where-Object { $_.FormatDescription -eq "JPEG" }
    }
    process {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
        if ($OfWindow) { 
        [Windows.Forms.Sendkeys]::SendWait("%{PrtSc}")        
        } else {
            [Windows.Forms.Sendkeys]::SendWait("{PrtSc}")        
        }

        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
        $bitmap = [Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetImage()    
        $ep = New-Object Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters  
        $ep.Param[0] = New-Object Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter ([System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder]::Quality, [long]100)  
        $screenCapturePathBase = "$pwd\ScreenCapture"
        $c = 0
        while (Test-Path "${screenCapturePathBase}${c}.jpg") {
            $c++}

        $bitmap.Save("${screenCapturePathBase}${c}.jpg", $jpegCodec, $ep)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setting the active window**

There are a couple things you need to do differently.  First, you need to set the active window this way:

[How to set foreground Window from Powershell event subscriber action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556872/how-to-set-foreground-window-from-powershell-event-subscriber-action)

**Getting the right window**

Next, you need to deal with the fact that IE spawns at least two processes.  So you need to grab the right window.

```
$h = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -like "My website*"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MainWindowHandle
```

**Taking the screenshot**

Now you can take the screenshot one of two ways.

1. Send PrtSc like JPBlanc showed you.

   ```
   Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms
   Start-Sleep -seconds 1

   ## Capture the current window 
   [System.Windows.Forms.Sendkeys]::SendWait("%{PrtSc}")
   ```
2. [Take-Screenshot script from PoschCode](http://poshcode.org/2021)

Answer (score 2):

Do you take care about that to capture the entire screen it's without % :

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms
Start-Sleep -seconds 1

## Capture the entire screen 
[System.Windows.Forms.Sendkeys]::SendWait("{PrtSc}") 

## Capture the current window 
[System.Windows.Forms.Sendkeys]::SendWait("%{PrtSc}")
```

Comment: I am hoping there is a way to set the script to capture only the IE window. if there is a way to make the IE window the "current" window that would work